# std::unique_ptr<Object> and many viewers (Object*), is it good design?

Tags: c++11, c++14, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

Say I want to manage an `Object` with `unique_ptr` in a sort of master class. However, I'm in a situation where many other classes need to use this `Object`. I'm passing `Object*` to them. I don't think this is a good design, but I can't find a right solution.

```
class Gadget1 {
  Object* obj_;
 public:
  Gadget1(Object* obj) : obj_(obj) {} 
};

class Gadget2 {
  // .. similar
};

class Worker {
  std::unique_ptr<Object> obj_;
 public:
  void init() {
    obj_ = std::make_unique<Object>(...);
    createGadget1(obj_.get());
    createGadget2(obj_.get());
    ...
  }
};
```

What'd be a right and safe approach? Should `Gadget` have `unique_ptr<Object>&` instead of `Object*`?

Assume that the lifetime of `Gadget1` is guaranteed to shorter than `Worker`.

Comment: The design is fine.

Comment: Will the lifetime of the created "gadgets" be less than the lifetime of the "worker"? Then it's fine. Considering pointers (and the smart pointers especially) as handling *ownership* the design you show is that `Worker` *owns* the data pointed to, and gives a *non-owning* pointer to the data to the gadgets. If you want shared ownership, or the lifetime of the gadgets might be longer than the lifetime of `Worker` then consider `std:shared_ptr` instead.

Comment: Objects owner functions may return `Object&` or `Object*`. If object may be not exists functions must return `Object*` (with null if not exists). Another non owner objects must not save `Object&` or `Object*` for future use. But use returned pointer returned only in current call.

Comment: @KerrekSB @Some programmer dude Thanks. I clarified in the post. The ownership is to `Worker` and it outlives the other classes.

Comment: It still doesn't compile. Lots of sloppiness in all the details.

Comment: @KerrekSB I was really writing a pseudo code; not a real code. I hope I don't need to write `Object` and factory functions. So my question was "is it good idea to give `Object*` or `Object&` from the unique_ptr owner?"

Comment: I'd be very very careful when relying on lifetime inclusion, but a raw pointer is definitely better than a reference to a smart pointer.

Comment: @Nullptr: The elisions are fine. I was more concerned about basic details about how to spell member functions and getting unique_ptrs right. I'm pretty sure you mean `obj_.get()` not `obj_->get()`, but it's hard to guess.

Comment: @KerrekSB Thanks! I would blame C++ :( Yes, . not ->.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your design is perfectly fine: smart pointers for the owner(s), and raw pointers for everyone else.

If you cannot guarantee that the objects outlives the observers, either:

- Notify the observers when an object dies so they can update their raw pointer, or
- Give `std::weak_ptr`s instead of raw pointers to the observers so they can check.

In any case, you should not use `std::unique_ptr<Object> &`: observers should not care about how the object's lifetime is ensured.
Plus, this adds nothing over a raw pointer: if the object dies, it's because its owner died, so the `std::unique_ptr` is dead too, and the reference is dangling -- back to square one.

Comment: "smart pointers for the owner(s), and raw pointers for everyone else." You nailed it. Thanks! I wanted to double check whether this was good.